# Mysql Add an AND clause to this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Maybe I am having a mind block here but I cant seem to get an AND clause to work properly in this query. I only want to return results where tbl_mod_Lessons.Approved = 1.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, 
                (SELECT AVG(intRating) FROM tbl_mod_LessonReviews LR WHERE LR.intLessonID = LS.intLessonID) rating,
                (SELECT strContentArea FROM tbl_mod_ContentAreas CA WHERE CA.intCAID = LS.intContentAreaID) strContentArea
            FROM tbl_mod_Lessons LS
            WHERE 
                (LS.strTitle LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strStandards LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strDescription LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strActivities LIKE $search_string) OR
                EXISTS(SELECT strContentArea FROM   tbl_mod_ContentAreas CA WHERE CA.intCAID = LS.intContentAreaID AND (CA.strContentArea LIKE $search_string))
                AND (LS.Approved = 1)
            ORDER BY ".$pager->getOrder("LS.intLessonID DESC")."
            LIMIT ".$pager->PageLimits();
```

as you can see iv tried to add it in, this does not break the query but its returning results where Approved = 0 .

Comment: Might be that AND takes residence over OR.  Put the entire chunk of OR stuff in parenthesis and that should fix it.  As is, it's evaluating the EXISTS() AND Approved = 1, then the other OR stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the one below. I added some brackets around your OR clauses.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, 
                (SELECT AVG(intRating) FROM tbl_mod_LessonReviews LR WHERE LR.intLessonID = LS.intLessonID) rating,
                (SELECT strContentArea FROM tbl_mod_ContentAreas CA WHERE CA.intCAID = LS.intContentAreaID) strContentArea
            FROM tbl_mod_Lessons LS
            WHERE (
                    (LS.strTitle LIKE $search_string) OR
                    (LS.strStandards LIKE $search_string) OR
                    (LS.strDescription LIKE $search_string) OR
                    (LS.strActivities LIKE $search_string) OR
                    EXISTS(SELECT strContentArea FROM   tbl_mod_ContentAreas CA WHERE CA.intCAID = LS.intContentAreaID AND (CA.strContentArea LIKE $search_string))
                )
                AND (LS.Approved = 1)
            ORDER BY ".$pager->getOrder("LS.intLessonID DESC")."
            LIMIT ".$pager->PageLimits();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add parentheses  like this around all the OR conditions to separate them from the AND

```
 WHERE 
                ((LS.strTitle LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strStandards LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strDescription LIKE $search_string) OR
                (LS.strActivities LIKE $search_string) OR
                EXISTS(SELECT strContentArea FROM   tbl_mod_ContentAreas CA 
                WHERE CA.intCAID = LS.intContentAreaID 
                AND (CA.strContentArea LIKE $search_string)))
                AND (LS.Approved = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround all the other `or` clauses with `( )`. Otherwise you're only `AND` the last clause.